# How to get output in the subprocess in real time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, subprocess

I'm trying to get **tail -f /var/log/syslog** to play the result in variable **data0** but without success.

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
 
def exit_data():
    with Popen(['tail -f', '/var/log/syslog'],stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE) as b:
        out,err = b.communicate()
    data0 = out.decode('utf-8')
    return data0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation, calling the [`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=popen#subprocess.Popen.communicate) method will *block* until the child process exits. Since you're calling `tail -f`, this will not return until the `tail` process exits, which only happens on EOF, errors, etc. So you don't see anything.

It looks like you want to continuously print the output of the `tail` subprocess in Python. To do this, you'd need to start the process, and continually (in a loop) read from its stdout and print the result. Do not call `communicate()`, and instead just read from the `stdout` attribute, which is a standard file-like object.

For example, this script would be `reader.py`:

```py
import subprocess as sp

# A dummy file to tail
filename = "/tmp/logfile"

proc = sp.Popen(
    ["tail", "-f", filename],
    stdout=sp.PIPE,
    stderr=sp.PIPE,
    text=True,  # I'm using text files, may not apply to your case
)
try:
    while True:
        print(proc.stdout.readline().rstrip("\n"))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Received interrupt, exiting")
    proc.terminate()
    proc.wait()
    print("Reaped child")
```

You can test this works by running the following snippet in another Python script, call it `writer.py`:

```py
import time
N_LINES = 100

filename = "/tmp/logfile"
with open(filename, "wt") as f:
    for _ in range(N_LINES):
        time.sleep(1)
        f.write("a new line of data\n")
        f.flush()
```

Run them with:

```sh
$ python3 writer.py &
$ python3 reader.py
a new line of data
a new line of data
a new line of data
a new line of data
a new line of data
^CReceived interrupt, exiting
Reaped child
```